# formula for solving systems of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, systems-of-equations

i've heard that there are these things called systems of equations, whereas there are 2 equations, like $2x+4=3y$ and $x+y=15$ my question is: is there a very simple formula for $ax+by=c$ and $dx+ey=f$? i've tried, like $5$ times, all with no reliable results.

Comment: You mean you want the solutions to the general case, as a function of the 6 coefficients?

Comment: From $ax+by=c$ extract (with care) $x=???$. PLug the expression in $dx+ey=f$. Extract (with care) $y=???$. Plug back to get $x$ (with care).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a formula, for example in terms of matrices. Let
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \cr  d & e \end{pmatrix},\; v=\begin{pmatrix} x \cr y \end{pmatrix} ,\; w=\begin{pmatrix} c \cr f \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then the system of equations is summarized as matrix equation $Av=w$. Suppose that $\det(A)=ae-bd\neq 0$. Then $v=A^{-1}w$ is the formula for the unique solution $v$. For $\det(A)=0$ we can make a case distinction, but the solutions may not be unique, or there may be no solution, e.g., for $a=b=0$ and $c=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They're called *Cramer's formulae*: first rewrite the linear system in standard form:
$$\begin{cases}x-3y=-4,\\x+y=15.\end{cases}$$
As the determinant of the system $\begin{vmatrix}1 &-3\\1&1\end{vmatrix}\ne 0$, the solutions are:
$$x=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}-4 &-3\\15&1\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}1 &-3\\1&1\end{vmatrix}},\qquad y= \frac{\begin{vmatrix}1 &-4\\1&15\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}1 &-3\\1&1\end{vmatrix}}.$$
This generalises to systems of $n$ linear equations with $n$ unknowns if their determinant is non-zero.